# The server failed to resume the transaction. Linq-To-SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm receiving a **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:6c00000001** when executing a Linq-To-SQL query.

Here is my repository call:

```
using (var ctx = new EntitiesDataContext())
{
    ctx.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
    ctx.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

    var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
    loadOptions.LoadWith<Company2QualifierLicense>(n => n.QualifierLicense);
    loadOptions.LoadWith<Company2QualifierLicense>(n => n.Company);
    loadOptions.LoadWith<QualifierLicense>(n => n.QualifierLicenseHoldStatus);
    loadOptions.LoadWith<QualifierLicense>(n => n.LicenseTrade);
    loadOptions.LoadWith<Company>(n => n.CompanyHoldStatus);
    ctx.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

    return ctx.Company2QualifierLicenses.Where(p => p.QualifierLicense.QualifierLicenseNumber == qualifierLicense).ToList();
}
```

Here is the SQL generated:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 VarChar(1000) = '11223344'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[CompanyID], [t0].[QualifierLicenseID], [t0].[InitiatedDate], [t0].[IsActive], [t0].[RowVersion], [t0].[LastUpdated], [t1].[QualifierLicenseID] AS [QualifierLicenseID2], [t1].[QualifierLicenseNumber], [t1].[LicenseTradeID], [t1].[LicenseExpirationDate], [t1].[FirstName], [t1].[LastName], [t1].[MailingAddress1], [t1].[MailingAddress2], [t1].[City], [t1].[StateAbbr], [t1].[ZIP], [t1].[Email], [t1].[Phone], [t1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion2], [t1].[LastUpdated] AS [LastUpdated2], [t3].[test], [t3].[LicenseTradeID] AS [LicenseTradeID2], [t3].[LicenseCode], [t3].[LicenseDescription], [t5].[QualifierLicenseHoldStatusID], [t5].[HoldReasonID], [t5].[QualifierLicenseID] AS [QualifierLicenseID3], [t5].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion3], [t5].[LastUpdated] AS [LastUpdated3], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [frontdesk].[QualifierLicenseHoldStatus] AS [t6]
    WHERE [t6].[QualifierLicenseID] = [t1].[QualifierLicenseID]
    ) AS [value], [t4].[CompanyID] AS [CompanyID2], [t4].[EIN], [t4].[CompanyName], [t4].[MailingAddress1] AS [MailingAddress12], [t4].[MailingAddress2] AS [MailingAddress22], [t4].[City] AS [City2], [t4].[StateAbbr] AS [StateAbbr2], [t4].[ZIP] AS [ZIP2], [t4].[Email] AS [Email2], [t4].[Phone] AS [Phone2], [t4].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion4], [t4].[LastUpdated] AS [LastUpdated4]
FROM [frontdesk].[Company2QualifierLicense] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN ([frontdesk].[QualifierLicense] AS [t1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS [test], [t2].[LicenseTradeID], [t2].[LicenseCode], [t2].[LicenseDescription]
        FROM [frontdesk].[LicenseTrade] AS [t2]
        ) AS [t3] ON [t3].[LicenseTradeID] = [t1].[LicenseTradeID]) ON [t1].[QualifierLicenseID] = [t0].[QualifierLicenseID]
INNER JOIN [frontdesk].[Company] AS [t4] ON [t4].[CompanyID] = [t0].[CompanyID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [frontdesk].[QualifierLicenseHoldStatus] AS [t5] ON [t5].[QualifierLicenseID] = [t1].[QualifierLicenseID]
WHERE [t1].[QualifierLicenseNumber] = @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[CompanyID], [t0].[QualifierLicenseID], [t1].[QualifierLicenseID], [t3].[LicenseTradeID], [t5].[QualifierLicenseHoldStatusID]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 Int = 241
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[CompanyHoldStatusID], [t0].[CompanyID], [t0].[HoldReasonID], [t0].[RowVersion], [t0].[LastUpdated]
FROM [frontdesk].[CompanyHoldStatus] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CompanyID] = @x1
```

As you can see I'm creating and disposing of the DataContext immediately after the database query, so no further calls can be made from the calling method.

I see that there are two queries issued to the database and my guess is that when issuing the second query to the database the transaction has been committed, but Linq-To-SQL should be smarter than that.

I'm using .NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2789.0

Any ideas?

## UPDATE Dec/21/2011

Here is another piece of the exception:
**The transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted by another session**

## UPDATE Dec/30/2011

A coworker found that this issue has been reported to Microsoft and it has been confirmed as a bug but it won't be fixed, and their recommendation is to move to Entity Framework.

Comment: It is read only, what do mean by committed

Comment: What happens if you execute without your dataloadoptions and objectttracking plus deferredloading enabled

Comment: @Pleun please read the exception message. It says that it could not resume the transaction. I still get exception without the object tracking and deferred loading. When I remove the data load options then it works fine, but it should work with them as well. That's the whole point to get as much related entites as possible in one single database trip.

Comment: I read the ex. Just because there is a transaction does not mean something has to be committed. Your query is readonly so why would there be a Commit. You are mentioning a commit in your question so is this part of a larger transaction or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker found that this issue has been reported to Microsoft and it has been confirmed as a bug but it won't be fixed, and their recommendation is to move to Entity Framework.

Answer (score -1):

A bit too long for comments.

You need to realize that eager loading in linq2sql does not work on multiple levels in a tree. So load b with a and c with b does not load a-b-c in one go.

http://www.lowendahl.net/showShout.aspx?id=190

This explains your additional second query.

Now why you get the exception I do not know.

Comment: I don't have a problem with extra queries issued to the database. If it is not possible to get all the data in one shot I'm ok with it. However, I don't see anything wrong in my query to be failing like that.

Comment: Can it be a timeout issue? What happens if you execute the raw sql in sql server?

Comment: it returns immediately. The query takes less than a second to complete.